# How to create drawable/bitmap with a nested image which has one corner out of the circle background?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawable

I need to create smth like below. Image should be nested inside the circle background and one of the corners should be out of this circle "pocket". I think we need smth like a mask but don't understand what instruments I can use to achieve this effect.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Compose?

Comment: Yes, now using Compose but any solutions are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a custom shape to an `Image` composable.
Something like:

```
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.xxx),
        contentDescription = "xxxx",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .clip(
                RoundedCornerShape(
                    topStartPercent = 50,
                    topEndPercent = 0, //square corner
                    bottomEndPercent = 50,
                    bottomStartPercent = 50
                )
            )
    )
```

[image]

Otherwise you can define you custom path using:

```
class MyShape(topStart: CornerSize) : Shape {

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val myPath = Path().apply {
            //....
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path = myPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried to customize smth like your first solution but it looks different. By design I should create the same as in screenshot attached. And it has some problems here. One of the issues here with a straight line to the left-top and right-bottom corners of inner image. But in solution you provided (and I tried before) we have these corners circled and it's what I'm trying to resolve here.